# How to call GeoLocation shortcode in custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Geolocation plugin to get my latitude and longitude  by downloading `http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-geolocation-js/` I am trying to use geolocation shortcode in another plugin. Kindly advice me if it possible to use Geolocation  shortcode to our custom plugin.

For example, shortcode to get latitude `<?php echo do_shortcode("[mmjs-lat]");?>` which gives latitude when i echo the code inside geolocation plugin. but when i used the same code in another plugin, not getting value. Kindly advice on this.

Answer (score 1):

Shortcodes are actually just function calls within the context of a specific string (the `do_shortcode` parameter) and the rest of the static global state of the whole Wordpress application.

You need to look inside [the shortcode implemenation of `[mmjs-lat]`](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-geolocation-js/trunk/wp-geolocation-js.php)and look which global variables it uses and then check if all are set in the way you need that shortcode to behave.